# Even with two tables I am having multi-part identifier error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
UPDATE [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20]
SET [dbo].[DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20].[TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE] = [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20].[TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE]
FROM [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20]
JOIN  [dbo].[DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20]  
ON [dbo].[DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20].[TXT_POLICY_NUMBER] = [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20].[TXT_POLICY_NUMBER];
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> The multi-part identifier "dbo.DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20.TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE" could not be bound.

Comment: That's not MySQL, it's SQL-Server. Please use correct tags.

Comment: Okay , Thank you for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You are updating [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20] table but the column you want to update is from a different table "SET [dbo].[DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20].[TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE]".

We can not do that, use the same table with UPDATE and SET functions.

Comment: Thanks @Naman, I tried what you said and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you learn how to use table aliases:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE = c.TXT_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_CODE
FROM [dbo].[DUMMY_15C_1000_2019_20] c JOIN
     [dbo].[DUMMY_15A_1000_2019_20] a 
     ON a.TXT_POLICY_NUMBER = c.TXT_POLICY_NUMBER;
```

(This also fixes the inconsistency between the `update` and `set` tables.)

Multipart table aliases are deprecated starting in SQL Server 2016.

Comment: You are right, although you (and myself) did not notice the table in `UPDATE` is not the same in the `SET`  :-)

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu . . . This fixes that issue, as the answer clearly states.

Comment: yes, I acknowledged your answer as correct. And I now acknowledge that I did not notice `a` in your solution refers to the correct table. That said, your comment, that 'this fixes this issue, as the answer clearly states' is a little too assertive :-) Man, this is 2021, age of Agile, Teams. Am I wrong or you were a bit too Sheldon Cooper? Rhetorics here, no answer expected, please :-)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ...... Thanks for your suggestion, I think aliases wold make it easier and less confusing .